# javascript Error for $ in ddpowerzoom library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am testing a script for image magnification with ddpowerzoom library

Below is the test code I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/ddpowerzoomer.js">


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready


    //EXAMPLE 1:
    $('#myimage').addpowerzoom()

    /*EXAMPLE 2:
    $('img.vacation').addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2,5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!
    })
    */

})

</script>



  <img id="myimage" src="ui_distorted.png" height="200" width="200"/>
```

Whenever I execute the script, I encounter the below error in Firebug:

> TypeError: $ is not a function [Break On This Error]
>
> $(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready

Could someone help me up with this?

Comment: Try replacing your link to jQuery with `<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and see if that solves it ?

Comment: or https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because ddpowerzoomer uses `jQuery.noConflict()` and takes control of $, therefore

`$(document).ready(function($){ ...`

needs to read

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ...`

I'm having the same issue and this is also my question, but no answer as yet!

Answer (score 0):

your jquery source path may be invalid. try using CDN with fallback

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='yourLocalPathForJquery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```